# Calculating the efficient frontier from expected returns and SD

Tags: r, optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

I'm trying to calculate the efficient frontier (and the optimal portfolio at the Sharpe ratio) given two vectors for a portfolio: (1) expected returns and (2) historical standard deviations.  I would like to be able to calculate this in R.  Using the `portfolioFrontier()` function of the `fPortfolio` package in R, I have successfully calculated the efficient frontier and optimal portfolio allocation at the Sharpe ratio using a time series of historical returns.  However, the `fPortfolio` package only appears to allow back-testing on a time series.  I would like to calculate the efficient frontier and optimal portfolio at the Sharpe ratio for future (i.e., expected) returns.  How can I do this?

Ideally this would be implemented with a function in R.  The closest resource I could find was from [this website](http://www.calculatinginvestor.com/2011/06/07/efficient-frontier-1/) using Octave code.  I successfully translated the code to R, but the efficient frontier doesn't appear to match (or be as accurate) as the one from the R package.

Here's my attempt in R (translating Octave code from the above website):

```
expectedReturns <- c(4, 2, 13, 10)
covarianceMatrix <- matrix(c(185, 86.5, 80, 20, 86.5, 196, 76, 13.5, 80, 76, 411, -19, 20, 13.5, -19, 25), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

# Calculate Efficient Frontier
unity <- rep(1, length(expectedReturns))
A <- unity %*% solve(covarianceMatrix) %*% unity
B <- unity %*% solve(covarianceMatrix) %*% expectedReturns
C <- expectedReturns %*% solve(covarianceMatrix) %*% expectedReturns
D <- A*C-B^2

mu = seq(0, 30, by=.1)
minVar = ((A*mu^2)-2*B*mu+C)/D
minSD = sqrt(minVar)

plot(minSD, mu)
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21464/how-to-perform-portfolio-optimization-with-user-defined-expected-return-and-vari

Comment: You say you want to input only standard deviations; but what about correlations?

Comment: Perhaps the function `mvFrontier`, in the devel version of package `NMOF`, does what you want: https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF/blob/master/R/portfolio.R#L80:L116 As for inputs, `m` are the expected returns and `var` is the covariance matrix.

Comment: Is a covariance matrix necessary?  If so, I wouldn't be able to produce good estimates of expected covariances apart from using historical ones.  But if it's necessary, feel free to provide a solution that has the following inputs: 1) vector of expected returns, and 2) a covariance matrix (which subsumes the vector of variances).  Thanks!

Comment: I do not think there is anything wrong with your code, it uses the well known formulas for A, B, C, D, etc that are in every textbook, as well as in the link you posted. Why do you say that the results are not accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, the function `mvFrontier` in the
development version of the [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) package may help
you. (Disclosure: I am the package maintainer.)  You
may get the [latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF).

Some remarks, first on correlation: an efficient
frontier shows portfolio risk, typically volatility,
compared with portfolio return. Portfolio volatility is
a function of both the volatilities of the assets and
the return-correlation between these assets, so you
cannot get rid of correlation.

The variance-covariance matrix may be decomposed into
the (matrix) product `S` times `C` times `S`, in which `S` is a
diagonal matrix with the standard deviations on its
main diagonal and zeros elsewhere, and in which `C` is
the correlation matrix.

Assume you have the following forecasts:

```
na <- 4                            ## number of assets 
vols <- c(0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.22)  ## forecast vols
m <- c(0.06, 0.12, 0.09, 0.07)     ## forecast returns
```

Then a covariance matrix for a constant correlation of
0.5 may be computed in this way:

```
const_cor <- function(rho, na) {
    C <- array(rho, dim = c(na, na))
    diag(C) <- 1
    C
}
var <- diag(vols) %*% const_cor(0.5, na) %*% diag(vols)
```

So you may want to experiment with different
assumptions about the correlations: it is difficult to
come up with valid arbitrary correlation matrices, but
what works is constant positive correlation (i.e.  all
pairwise correlations are 0.1, or 0.2, ...).
Depending on the actual data, the correlation may make 
little difference to the results (see this [note](https://ssrn.com/abstract=2214376), for instance).

Another remark, on matrix derivations (as in the link
you provided): I would prefer to tackle the problem as
a optimisation problem instead of following some
analytical approach. The advantage is that you may want
to introduce restrictions (not allow short shales,
say), which becomes more difficult with the analytical
approach.

So here would be an example for calling `mvFrontier`:

```
library("NMOF")
wmax <- 1     ## maximum holding size
wmin <- 0.0   ## minimum holding size
rf <- 0.02

## without cash
p1 <- mvFrontier(m, var, wmin = wmin, wmax = wmax, n = 50)

## with cash
p2 <- mvFrontier(m, var, wmin = wmin, wmax = wmax, n = 50, rf = rf)

plot(p1$volatility, p1$return, pch = 19, cex = 0.5, type = "o",
     xlab = "Expected volatility",
     ylab = "Expected return")
lines(p2$volatility, p2$return, col = grey(0.5))
abline(v = 0, h = rf)
```

[image: frontiers]

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved for fPortfolio package using SetEstimator. Example below:

```
expectedReturns <- c(4, 2, 13, 10)
covarianceMatrix <- matrix(c(185, 86.5, 80, 20, 86.5, 196, 76, 13.5, 80, 76, 411, -19, 20, 13.5, -19, 25), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

covtEstimator <- function (x,data,spec) {
x.mat = as.matrix(x)
list(mu=expectedReturns,Sigma=covarianceMatrix)
}

# Calculate Efficient Frontier
defaultSpec <- portfolioSpec()
setEstimator(defaultSpec) <- 'covtEstimator'
efficientPortfolio(yourreturndata, defaultSpec, constraints = "LongOnly")
```

Additional reference : Page 293 in [this pdf](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/fPortfolio/inst/PortfolioOptimizationSample.pdf?revision=4196&root=rmetrics&pathrev=4910)